# PayUMoney payment gateway error after payment

Tags: php, payment-gateway, payu

After payment is done, I am not redirected to my website using payumoney payment gateway. I am receiving following error. Any help would be appreciated.

URL: https://test.payumoney.com/payment/postBackParam.do

### Content

HTTP Status 404 - /settlement/WEB-INF/jsp/.jsp

type Status report

message /settlement/WEB-INF/jsp/.jsp

description The requested resource is not available.
Apache Tomcat/7.0.54

Comment: Hi, I am getting same error, please let me know as well if u found answer.

Comment: I'm getting the same error too... Have sent an email to the tech support team. No reply yet.

Comment: even i too getting same error. my code was working nicely before, but suddenly it turned into this error, can any one tell whats the issue?

Comment: @adarshaU : I just post an answer, It was happening due to lengthy Productinfo param in my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While submitting the purchase info to PayUMoney, there is a field called Productinfo which takes JSON data that contains purchase info like below.

`Productinfo = {“paymentParts”:[{
"name":"abc",
"description":"abcd",
"value":"500",
"isRequired":"true",
“settlementEvent” : “EmailConfirmation”
},
{
"name":"xyz",
"description":"wxyz",
"value":"1500",
"isRequired":"false",
“settlementEvent”: “EmailConfirmation”
}],
{“paymentIdentifiers”:[{
"field":"CompletionDate",
"value":"31/10/2012”
},
{
"field":"TxnId",
"value":"abced"
}]}`

When this JSON data is too long, it can not handle the request properly and fails to complete the process.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem while integrating PayU with our app. I talked to the PayU tech team regarding this. Santosh has answered it correctly.

Just to add to that, as per PayU's tech team, the limit on length of the JSON data is 100.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using PHP then store the JSON format as string

```
$productinfo1 = '{"paymentParts":[{"name":"Designs","description":"Qty : 33","value":null,"isRequired":"true"}],"paymentIdentifiers":[{"field":"CompletionDate","value":"31/10/2012"},{"field":"txnid","value":"21827f29b9e7c4a3b211"}]}';
```

Note: Not required to send all products info, as long string leads to payment gateway error.

```
$productinfo = json_decode(json_encode($productinfo1));

$hash_string = $merchant_key . '|' . $txn_id . '|' . number_format($total, 2, '.', '')  . '|' . $productinfo . '|' . $name . '|' . $email . '|' . $id . '||||||||||' . $salt;
$hash = hash('sha512', $hash_string);
```

Post the `$hash` value to pay money.

Answer (score 0):

This is something that might occur at some point of time in test mode because of rigorous testing that happens on 
test server. It is nothing to worry about.

Comment: No that was not the problem.